# How to combine two varibles in grok parser

Tags: logging, datadog

My log Sample:

```
Process Process[spinup-app-3,5,main] has been running for 9740 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
```

My Current Grok Praser

```
rule1 Process\s+Process\[%{data:appName}-%{integer:appID},%{integer:Count},main\]\s+%{data}\s%{number:duration}\s+%{data}\s%{number:duration}\s+ms
```

```
Current Output
{
  "duration": [
    9740,
    2000
  ],
  "appName": "spinup-app",
  "appID": 3,
  "Count": 5
}
```

I want to combine `appName` and `appID` to form `task` (Like shown below) how can I achieve this?

```
desired Output
{
  "duration": [
    9740,
    2000
  ],
  "task": "spinup-app-3"
  "appName": "spinup-app",
  "appID": 3,
  "Count": 5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [String Builder Processor](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui#string-builder-processor) after your Grok Parser in your pipeline to create the `task` attribute.

`%{appName}-%{appID}`